# useLocation changes in the parent useEffect function scope but nested functions use older value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, stomp

There is a custom hook

```
const useStompSubscription = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const routerLocation = useLocation();
  const namespace = useSelector(bootstrapNamespaceSelector);
  console.log("routerLocation", routerLocation); // logs correctly when routerLocation changes
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect", routerLocation); // logs correctly when routerLocation changes
    if (!namespace) {
      return;
    }

    const stompClient = getSTOMPClient(
      namespace,
      function(message) {
        console.log("onReceiveQueueMessage", routerLocation); // logs only the first route where initialization happened
        if (
          routerLocation.pathname !== QUEUE_PATH &&
          routerLocation.pathname !== WORKLOAD_PATH
        )
          return;

        let payload = JSON.parse(message.body);
        if (payload.status === PRINTED || payload.status === CANCELLED) {
          dispatch(onDeletePrintingQueueAction(payload));
        } else {
          dispatch(onCreateOrUpdatePrintingQueueAction(payload));
        }
      },
      function(message) {
        console.log("onReceiveManifestMessage", routerLocation); // logs only the first route where initialization happened

        if (routerLocation.pathname !== DELIVERY_MANIFEST_PATH) return;

        let payload = JSON.parse(message.body);
        dispatch(onCreateOrUpdateDeliveryPackageAction(payload));
      },
    );

    stompClient.activate();

    return () => {
      stompClient.deactivate();
    };
  }, [dispatch, namespace, routerLocation, routerLocation.pathname]);
};
```

It calls `getSTOMPClient` function, passing 2 callbacks - `onReceiveQueueMessage` and `onReceiveManifestMessage`, which access the `routerLocation` from the parent scope.

```
let instance;

export const getSTOMPClient = (
  namespace,
  onReceiveQueueMessage,
  onReceiveManifestMessage,
) => {
  if (isNil(instance)) {
    let host;
    let url;
    if (window.location.port === "") {
      host = `${window.location.hostname}`;
    } else {
      host = `${window.location.hostname}:${window.location.port}`;
    }
    if (window.location.protocol === "https:") {
      url = `wss://${host}/ws`;
    } else {
      url = `ws://${host}/ws`;
    }

    instance = new Client({
      brokerURL: url,
      onConnect() {
        const queueTopic = `/ui/${namespace}/queue`;
        this.queueSubscription = this.subscribe(
          queueTopic,
          onReceiveQueueMessage,
        );

        const dmTopic = `/ui/${namespace}/dm`;
        this.dmSubscription = this.subscribe(dmTopic, onReceiveManifestMessage);
      },

      onDisconnect() {
        const defaultSub = { unsubscribe: noop };
        const queueSubscription = defaultTo(this.queueSubscription, defaultSub);
        const dmSubscription = defaultTo(this.dmSubscription, defaultSub);
        queueSubscription.unsubscribe();
        dmSubscription.unsubscribe();
      },
      // Helps during debugging, remove in production
      debug: str => {
        console.log(new Date(), str);
      },
    });
  }

  return instance;
};
```

What I expect is that whenever the callbacks are fired they will access the `routerLocation` from `useStompSubscription` scope.

The `console.log("routerLocation", routerLocation);` and `console.log("useEffect", routerLocation);` log correctly the changes.

However in the callbacks always the first `routerLocation` is used, the changes doesn't seem to affect it.

This seems to be simple closure.
What am I missing in here?

Comment: `getSTOMPClient` returns a singleton, no matter how many times you call it with different parameters it will always return the same object (called instance in your code).

Comment: @HMR yes I am aware of it being the same instance. But the callbacks access a variable outside the scope of the instance, which is changes, no?

Comment: No, you pass callbacks to getStompClient that are only used once. When the component re renders you re create the closure values and re create the callbacks that uses these new values but these new callbacks are never used.

Comment: @HMR yes re-creating the instance fixes the problem. You can post an answer and I'll accept it. Also if possible please give some more explanation. Thanks a lot!